# How pass an environment var from child to parent?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

To update an environment var called DOLP in child process and this change should be visible in the parent process.
The code is as follows:

```
    int main(void) {
        int cid1 ,i;
        char ear[20]="DOLP=7";
        putenv(ear);

        printf("parent(main) process %d, ppid is %d  t %d \n",getpid(),
                getppid(),atoi(getenv("DOLP")));
        fflush(stdout);
        cid1=fork();

        if ((cid1 == 0)) {
          //child process ...
          int sd =atoi(getenv("DOLP")) -1;
          char v[10];
          sprintf(v,"%d",sd);
          setenv("DOLP",v,1);
          sleep(2);
          printf("c process pid %d, ppid is %d sd value: %d\n", getpid(),
                  getppid(),atoi(getenv("DOLP")));
          fflush(stdout);
          sleep(1);
          } 
      else{
           sleep(2);
           //parent process...
           int sd =atoi(getenv("DOLP")) -1;
           sprintf(ear,"DOLP=%d",sd);
           putenv(ear);
           sleep(1);
           printf("parent(main) process %d, ppid is %d sd value %d\n",
                    getpid(),getppid(),atoi(getenv("DOLP")));
           fflush(stdout);
           }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get as follows:

```
parent(main) process 25958, ppid is 25955  t 7 
c process pid 25968, ppid is 25958 sd value: 6
parent(main) process 25958, ppid is 25955 sd value 6
```

actually i want the parent to print 5 for sd value.
Now how to make the child updates on DOLP be visible in parent process.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, not directly. Parents and children are different processes with separate environments. Setting an environment variable in the child has no effect on the parent and vice versa.

The exception to this is when a child process is first created. Its initial environment is a copy of the parent's environment. But after the child is created it is completely separate.

If you want one process to change the environment of another you'll need to set up explicit communication between the two and have the child send a message to the parent telling it to change its environment. This could be via a pipe, socket, shared memory, or other interprocess communication mechanism.

Comment: By default, the child's environment is a copy of the parent's — unless the `execve()` system call was used to specify an alternative environment.

Comment: Question was asked  creating main(parent) and child . The parent and child should take turns to count down the environment var DOLP. To achieve this output, you will synchronize Parent, Child to repeatedly sleep (sleep() call), awaken, print, and flush the printed line (fflush() call). And my doubt is if this is possible.