# How does the command 'ssh-agent /bin/bash' start a new shell with the agent's environment variables set?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh-agent

I am just trying to better understand running ssh-agent. Below are three samples of how I have run ssh-agent. Note that for each example I close my session, and then start out with a fresh bash shell. In each new shell I confirm that ssh-agent is not running. I'm running bash shell (on Ubuntu/WSL). Question after the code samples.

If I want to start ssh-agent in the current shell, I can run the agent, and then manually set the environment variables that the agent returns.

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-grVAkSC9cY98/agent.18454; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=18455; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 18455;
$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-grVAkSC9cY98/agent.18454
$ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
$ SSH_AGENT_PID=18455
$ export SSH_AGENT_PID
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

More easily I can just use `eval`

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 18478
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

If I want to start ssh-agent in a new shell I can run `ssh-agent /bin/bash` rather than starting the shell, and then repeating the previous command (I know that the new shell can inherent ssh-agent from the parent shell, but I'm just interested in understanding what is going on with this command)

```
$ ssh-agent /bin/bash
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

Now the question: It seems like the command `ssh-agent` does not set the environment variables, but only returns them as a command string that must be evaluated (I'm curious as to why it works this way). How does the command (or two commands on the same line) `ssh-agent /bin/bash` start the new shell with the environment variables set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `ssh-agent` can run *any* command in an environment where `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` are available. `ssh-agent /bin/bash` is just the special case where that command happens to be a shell.

With no argument, it simply outputs code suitable for use with `eval` to create the same environment, rather than starting a new process *with* that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I really should have thought to look at the ssh-agent manual. The first answer made me think of doing that. From the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html):

> There are two main ways to get an agent set up.  The first is at  the
> start of an X session, where all other windows or programs are
> started as children of the ssh-agent program.  The agent starts a
> command under which its environment variables are exported, for
> example ssh-agent xterm &.  When the command terminates, so does  the
> agent.
>
> The second method is used for a login session.  When ssh-agent is
> started, it prints the shell commands required to set its  environment
> variables, which in turn can be evaluated in the  calling shell, for
> example eval `ssh-agent -s`.

Everything makes sense when thinking of login and non-login sessions. Of course, I'm still curious as to why in a login session ssh-agent prints the environment variable shell commands rather than setting the environment variables itself.

Comment: *Of course, I'm still curious as to why in a login session ssh-agent prints the environment variable shell commands rather than setting the environment variables itself.* -- You can't change the environment of a parent process; you can only change the environment variables of yourself, and thereby your future children. In the `ssh-agent /bin/bash` case, the new copy of `/bin/bash` is a child; in the `ssh-agent` case, there _are_ no children, so the parent process needs to be responsible for changing its own variables; hence emitting `eval`able code.

Comment: The ssh-agent prints the environment variable shell commands because it cannot set the environment variables.   That is, absolutely no program can set the environment for the calling shell.  And so, ssh-agent provides you with the commands that you can eval in the current shell (the parent program) to set the variables.  And that is also why ssh-agent provides you a mechanism to start a child shell (or xterm session or whatever).  ssh-agent CAN export environment variables for child processes.

Comment: See f/e [How to pass an environment var from child to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169038/how-pass-an-environment-var-from-child-to-parent) re: the constraints that drive this decision.

Comment: @Mark, ...well, no program using published, documented, portable interfaces suitable for production use. There are horrible awful hacks like attaching to your parent with a debugger and telling it to inject a `setenv()` call, but... eww.

Comment: @DavidG, ...another one of the many Q&A entries on the topic already in our knowledge base is [Can the child process affect parent process's environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360679/can-the-child-process-affect-parent-process-environment)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I'm still new to Linux, but this all makes perfect sense.

Comment: Note: This type of question is not allowed, so I'll have to delete it. I'll let it up for a few hours so anybody who responded can see why I am deleting it.